# Output of mysql table row to web page

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a bit of code which I am using or trying to use in one of my php pages which is getting logged data from a mysql table (being search-log) and outputting it to:

```
$content .= $data['search_term'];
# (Row being "search_term")
```

The problem I have is, when it outputs to the web page, it isn't user friendly and prints it out something like:

`teddyhappybrownorangelimewdonkeyminecraftdiskdrive`

Is there a way I can output the result with each word on a different line using `<BR>?`

I'd also like to be able to change the default font as well.

```
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user     = "ultbrd";
$mysql_password = "wf_7a41hvZ@";
$mysql_database = "ultbrd_1";
$bd             = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");// we are now connected to database

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search-log"); // selecting data through mysql_query()

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $content .= $data['search_term'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea you need to add '
' on each word in your code. Please change your line like below and try

```
$content .= $data['search_term'].'<br>';
```

If you want to make 4 words in a line . you can add a iterator and check. like below

```
$cnt= 1;
$content = '<div class="search_result">';
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 if($cnt % 4 == 0)
    $content .= $data['search_term'].'<br>';
 else
    $content .= $data['search_term'].' ';
$cnt++;
}
$content .= '</div>';
```

Add some css class to the container and add the css to change the font like below

```
<style type="text/css">
.search_result { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font- size:15px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Great, I'm getting there. Is there a way I can change the font face and maybe have 3-4 on each like instead of one on each line? Thank you.

Comment: You can , I have updated my answer. please have a look

Comment: If you want make 3 words in a line, change 4 to 3 in the if condition

Comment: Absolutely amazing. Thank you.
Is there a way to only display the top 15 results taken from the database? Thank you.

Comment: Is there also a way to add a bad words filter and place * stars in place?